# what logic does injector use to determine which scope to pass to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I define a controller I can request scope object as a argument:

```
angular.module('custom', []).controller('custom', function($scope) {});
```

During run-time the injector initializes the controller. My question is how it determines which `$scope` object to inject? Does it depend on which component triggers controller initialization? 
For example, if a controller's initialization is triggered by `ng-controller="custom"` directive or if the directive requires a controller:

```
angular.module('custom', []).directive(function() {
    return {
       "controller":"custom",
    }
});
```

then I would guess that the scope that is associated with the DOM element on which the directive is found will be injected in the controller.

So if choosing the right scope depends on which component triggers controller initialization, what are the ways to trigger initialization of a controller and what scope will be selected then?

Answer (score 0):

An angular application has one root-scope, a controller merely extend that scope creating child scopes.

The $rootElement is the element being bootstrapped either using ng-app or angular.bootstrap().

The association with elements and your scope is just helpful with debugging I guess. Try opening your console while inspecting an html, then run in commandline "angular.element($0)" to get the scope to "angular.element($0).scope()"

A directive can have isolated scope. This is because a third party directive doesn't need to be influenced by its parent's scope.

A controller can be created using a $controller service and is registered using a $controllerProvider.

ng-controller instantiate a controller like the $controller service does. You can instantiate as much controller with the same name as much as you like at least with a $controller service (am not sure with ng-controller though).